# Java: String split(): I want it to include the empty strings at the end

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following String:

```
String str = "\nHERE\n\nTHERE\n\nEVERYWHERE\n\n";
```

If you just print this, it would output like this (Of course the `\n` wouldn't be "literally" printed):

```
\n
HERE\n
\n
THERE\n
\n
EVERYWHERE\n
\n
\n
```

When I call the method `split("\n")`, I want to get all strings between the new line (`\n`) characters even empty strings at the end.

For example, if I do this today:

```
String strArray[] = str.split("\n");

System.out.println("strArray.length - " + strArray.length);
for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++)
    System.out.println("strArray[" + i + "] - \"" + strArray[i] + "\"");
```

I want it to print out like this (Output A):

```
strArray.length - 8
strArray[0] - ""
strArray[1] - "HERE"
strArray[2] - ""
strArray[3] - "THERE"
strArray[4] - ""
strArray[5] - "EVERYWHERE"
strArray[6] - ""
strArray[7] - ""
```

Currently, it prints like this (Output B), and any ending empty strings are skipped:

```
strArray.length - 6
strArray[0] - ""
strArray[1] - "HERE"
strArray[2] - ""
strArray[3] - "THERE"
strArray[4] - ""
strArray[5] - "EVERYWHERE"
```

How do I make the `split()` method include the empty strings like in Output A? I, of course, could write a multi-line piece of code, but wanted to know, before I waste my time trying to implement that, if there was a simple method or an extra two or so lines of code to help me. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom good point, I was confused since I was getting *only* empty strings in my case (which, in reality meant, "only trailing empty strings") I've attempted to clarify now, thanks!

Answer (score 190, accepted):

use `str.split("\n", -1)` (with a negative `limit` argument). When `split` is given zero or no `limit` argument it discards trailing empty fields, and when it's given a positive `limit` argument it limits the number of fields to that number, but a *negative* limit means to allow any number of fields and not discard trailing empty fields. This is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and the behavior is taken from Perl.

Answer (score 9):

The one-argument split method is specified to ignore trailing empty string splits but the version that takes a "limit" argument preserves them, so one option would be to use that version with a large limit.

```
String strArray[] = str.split("\n", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Do you know the syntax to do this?

Comment: +1 http://ideone.com/BQRyII

Comment: using negative limit is better than using max int imho

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like the Guava utility for splitting:

```
System.out.println(Iterables.toString(
   Splitter.on('\n').split(input)));
```

Then if you want to configure empty string behaviour, you can do so:

```
System.out.println(Iterables.toString(
   Splitter.on('\n').omitEmptyStrings().split(input)));
```