# String split not working when there is no text in one side

Tags: java, split

Trying to split a "username:password" from a TextArea, to a TextAreaUser and TextAreaPass, but when the input is "username:" or ":password" it stops.

```
    private void jButtonStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    String[] lines = jTextAreaScrap.getText().split("\n");    
    String[] divid = null;
    String user, pass;

    jTextAreaUser.setText(null);
    jTextAreaPass.setText(null);

    for (int i=0; i<= lines.length; i++){

        if (lines[i].contains(":")) {

            divid = lines[i].split(":");

            user = divid[0]; 
            pass = divid[1];

            jTextAreaUser.append(divid[0]+"\n");
            jTextAreaPass.append(divid[1]+"\n");

        }
}
```

Stack Trace :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at DorkCreator.DorkCreator.jButtonStartActionPerformed(DorkCreator.java:135)
        at DorkCreator.DorkCreator.access$000(DorkCreator.java:14)
        at DorkCreator.DorkCreator$1.actionPerformed(DorkCreator.java:50)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: @tobygriffin i've tried to add: if (divid[1] == null){
                jTextAreaPass.append("\n");
            }

Comment: can you post up your stack trace?

Comment: @KickButtowski http://pastebin.com/h2364CP6

Comment: Shouldn't be `for (int i=0; i<= lines.length; i++){` something like that `for (int i=0; i< lines.length; i++){`?

Comment: @Yser wondering how the op could solve it's issue too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because string split will remove "empties".

Change to:

```
divid = lines[i].split(":", -1);
```

[Java: String split(): I want it to include the empty strings at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939675/java-string-split-i-want-it-to-include-the-empty-strings-at-the-end)

Comment: Worked perfectly, what if I wanna skip that kind of lines("user:" ":pass")?

Comment: So if you want to filter them, just use your original string split and check if divid.length == 2. But I would recommend explicitly defining what you consider valid input and using a regular expression to validate the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<= lines.length; i++)
```

Your array size is 2, loop will go to index 2 if you use "<=", but the max index is 1

Replace by

```
for (int i=0; i< lines.length; i++)
```

Edit : Thanks Yser, that's a bad copy and paste while re-editing to be clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload split method. Also your index needs to be < not <=

```
private void jButtonStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

String[] lines = jTextAreaScrap.getText().split("\n");    
String[] divid = null;
String user, pass;

jTextAreaUser.setText(null);
jTextAreaPass.setText(null);

for (int i=0; i< lines.length; i++){

    if (lines[i].contains(":")) {

        divid = lines[i].split(":", 2);

        user = divid[0]; 
        pass = divid[1];

        jTextAreaUser.append(divid[0]+"\n");
        jTextAreaPass.append(divid[1]+"\n");

    }
}
```