# Split on string giving false result

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string a follows

```
String caret= "Y^LEAD_PROJECT_V.vw^View LEAD_PROJECT_V.vw^INF^View^Extension^RECOMPILE^Unit Test^Recompile - Test ^Test View PROJECT_V.vw^^SIMPLE^^^^^^^";
```

I want to split this string with `^`. So I used the following code to split it

```
String[] split = caret.split("\\^");
System.out.println(split.length);
```

**`split.length` obtained :**

```
12
```

**`split.length` required:**

```
19 // as there are 18 caret symbols in the string
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong in it. Whatever regex I use, I'm getting the same result.  Also I cannot modify the string `caret`.

Can anyone please help me in getting `19` as array length.

Comment: Split does not keep empty strings. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13939902/2006429) to keep empty strings.

Comment: @usandfriends It worked now. Thanx for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `"\\^",-1` like this:

```
  String[] split = caret.split("\\^",-1);
```

With using `-1` you can include empty string, having an output = `19`.
For more info take a look at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Can you explain what the `-1` means?

Comment: Thank you. It worked as expected. :)