# Splitting String in Java with empty elements

Tags: java, string, split

I'm reading from a .csv File line by line. One line could look for example as following: `String str = "10,1,,,,"`.

Now I would like to split according to ",": `String[] splitted = str.split(",");` The problem now is that this only results in 2 elements but I would like to have 5 elements, the first two elements should contain 10 and 1 and the other 3 should be just an empty String.

Another example is `String str = "0,,,,,"` which results in only one element but I would like to have 5 elements.

The last example is `String str = "9,,,1,,"` which gives 2 elements (9 and 1), but I would like to have 5 elements. The first element should be 9 and the fourth element should be 1 and all other should be an empty String.

How can this be done?

Comment: "`"0,,,,,"` ... I would like to have 5 elements." 5 commas means 6 elements, if you retain them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use it with `-1` parameter

```
String[] splitted = str.split(",", -1);
```

This has been discussed before, e.g.
[Java: String split(): I want it to include the empty strings at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939675/java-string-split-i-want-it-to-include-the-empty-strings-at-the-end)

But `split` really **shouldn't be** the way you parse a csv, you could run into problems when you have a String value containing a comma

```
23,"test,test","123.88"
```

`split` would split the row into 4 parts:

```
[23, "test, test", "123.88"]
```

and I don't think you want that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you parse a csv file instead?

Comment: I'd look for some library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101100/csv-api-for-java or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843997/csv-parsing-in-java-working-example

Answer (score 3):

split only drops trailing delimeters by default. You can turn this off with

```
String str = "9,,,1,,";
String[] parts = str.split(",", -1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

prints

```
[9, , , 1, , ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass `-1` (or any negative number, actually) as a second parameter to split:

```
System.out.println("0,,,,,".split(",", -1).length); // Prints 6.
```

Comment: First argument of `split` is a String, not char ;)