# Reading specific column of file line by line in Java exception

Tags: java, file

I have this code below.What i'm trying to do is read a text file which every line has Strings separated by tabs.For example (name \t country \t id \t content) where \t is the tab.Then i want to print only the 2nd column of each line.I'm trying split the whole line to tokens but it works fine only for the 1st line of the file and then it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Also it works perfect when i try to print only the 1st column (tokens[0]) but not for tokens[1] which I need.So what am I need to do to get the 2nd columns of each line?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("a.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis)) ;
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        String[] tokens=line.split("\\t");
        System.out.println(tokens[1]);  

    }
    fis.close();
}
```

Comment: If the input is valid, your code should be fine. Check the input file.

Comment: You should not escape \ character, Try this: line.split("\t")

Comment: If the input is not valid,can i make it work somehow if i split the tokens with spaces? like String[] tokens=line.split("\\s") ?

Comment: @cricket_007 "\t" is tab, "\\t" is "\t" text.

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed. You grab something in the second position of the array, not the "first". I recommend splitting on `"\\s+"` and using an if-statement before accessing the array

Comment: @andrucz - Ah, now I understand what you meant, my bad

Comment: @andrucz Because split takes a regex, using the the escape or a literal tab works the same.

Comment: @erickson you are right. my bad.

Comment: You'll have to define better requirements. Are you saying that tokens are separated by spaces, not tabs? Or that tokens can be separated by spaces or tabs? Or maybe it's just tabs, and it's okay to skip lines that don't have a value in every column. How do you want it to work?

Comment: I just wrote:if(tokens.length>1) above the System.out.println and it worked.

Comment: Okay, so you should have said that you want to skip invalid lines in your question.

Comment: i didnt thought that there were invalid lines in the file thats why i didnt mention it

Comment: I appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if no tab exists in the line you get the exception.

you should check if tokens.length()>1 before accessing the second element.

Comment: This worked!!! I just put an if state above the print.Thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 1):

If the line looks for example like this

```
asdf\t\t\t
```

Then you have a problem. You should use

```
String[] tokens=line.split("\\t", -1);
```

See [Java: String split(): I want it to include the empty strings at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939675/java-string-split-i-want-it-to-include-the-empty-strings-at-the-end)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 :

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("a.txt"))) {
        stream.map(line -> line.split("\\t"))
                .filter(tokens -> tokens.length > 1)
                .forEach(tokens -> System.out.println(tokens[1]));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't print the desired column, it prints any columns.