# java String split function

Tags: java, string, split

In java doc of [`public String\[\] split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

we can find example:

> The string `"boo:and:foo"`, for example, yields the following results with these expressions
>
> Regex          Result
>
> o                       `{ "b", "", ":and:f" }`

What is the second result `""` come from?  From between `b` and `oo`, or `oo` and `:and:f`?

Comment: this return two string, 'b', ':and:f', but why the origin '' not found? I know '+' means the 'o' must occur at least one time

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera if use split("o+", -1), then three string return, 'b', ':and:f' and '', don't know what happen....why the last '' is counted but the '' between 'o''o' is not counted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the delimiter `o` and there are two delimiters next to eachother, it yields an empty string. So for instance if you have a String `foo::bar` and split it with `:` you will get `{"foo", "", "bar"}` because the space between `::` is treated as an empty string when splitting.

If you would like to split without having any empty strings, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values).

Ending empty strings?

> When split is given zero or no limit argument it discards trailing empty fields

Ref: [Java: String split(): I want it to include the empty strings at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939675/java-string-split-i-want-it-to-include-the-empty-strings-at-the-end)

Comment: what about last oo then? . No empty string token in the end.

Comment: @omkarsirra Yes, the empty strings at the end fall off (take a look at this for some in depth discussion about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939675/java-string-split-i-want-it-to-include-the-empty-strings-at-the-end

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a regex engine, locations between characters also count. So, the regex engine sees the `boo:and:foo` string as

```
<EMPTY>b<EMPTY>o<EMPTY>o<EMPTY>:<EMPTY>a<EMPTY>n<EMPTY>d<EMPTY>:<EMPTY>f<EMPTY>o<EMPTY>o<EMPTY>
               ^between^                                                       ^between^
```

As the first `^between^` is not at the end of the string, `split` keeps the empty location (string) in the results. The trailing empty elements are removed as the end since the `int limit` argument is `0` by default. If you pass `-1` (a non-positive value), all the trailing empty elements will be present in the resulting array. See [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) reference.