# Java String.split not working well

Tags: java, string, split

I'll give an example to clarify my problem:

```
String goodSplit="a@@b";
String badSplit="a@@";
String[] goodArray = goodSplit.split("@");
String[] badArray = badSplit.split("@");
```

The `goodArray` looks like:  `["a" , "", "b"]`

The `badArray` looks like: `["a"]` but I wanted  to get `["a", "", ""]` and preserve trailing empty elements.

How can I solve it?
Maybe you can recommend me on another way to split those strings?

Comment: You should also have a look here at my answer which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119032/java-string-split-function/39119106#39119106